# ConcurrentModificationException in rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am occasionally getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` exception when running rosjava. It happens when serializing the `tfMessage`. I am publishing tf messages at 10hz.

The stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-14" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:782)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:754)
    at org.ros.message.tf.tfMessage.serialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.ros.message.Message.serialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.ros.internal.message.old_style.MessageSerializer.serialize(MessageSerializer.java:39)
    at org.ros.internal.transport.OutgoingMessageQueue.writeMessageToChannel(OutgoingMessageQueue.java:79)
    at org.ros.internal.transport.OutgoingMessageQueue.access$100(OutgoingMessageQueue.java:38)
    at org.ros.internal.transport.OutgoingMessageQueue$Writer.loop(OutgoingMessageQueue.java:56)
    at org.ros.concurrent.CancellableLoop.run(CancellableLoop.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Is this a known problem, and is there any way to circumvent it?

I also sometimes getting buffer overflow exceptions in the same code.

This only seems to affect tf messages. I have not seen the problem with any other messages that I am publishing.

I checked out rosjava on March 2nd. I am on Ubuntu 11.10 using ROS electric.

I notice that the stack trace indicates that I am using the old style message serializer. Is there a way to use the new style message serializer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29915/concurrentmodificationexception-in-rosjava/) by [LawrieGriffiths](https://answers.ros.org/users/1997/lawriegriffiths/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the process of switching to the new style messaging system. However, it probably won't fix this. Please file an issue with stack trace and any code you can offer to help reproduce the issue. http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0